# Pre-rendering in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am simulating an electromagnetic wave and plotting a 3D representation of it. The calculations take a while to do and I plot one frame at a time. This works ok, but when I start adding interpolation and lighting, it gets really laggy. I tried using mov2avi, but the video file ends up being corrupted and I can't get it to work right. Is there a way to pre-render a bunch of frames and plot them all at the end? Or should I keep trying to figure out mov2avi?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to pre-render a bunch of frames and plot them all at the end?

The [`visible`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html) property can help to limit the load.

```
figure
set(1, 'Visible', 'off')
plot([3 4], [4 5])
set(1, 'Visible', 'on')
```

You could also have a look at the `renderer` property but in theory, Matlab choose the good one automatically.